# Why is my subview's frame resized?

Tags: objective-c, frame, subviews

I have scroll view like subview of head view and subview of scroll view.
[image]

When app is running I set frame of my subview (map view) and after scrolling this frame is changing back.

Autoresize subviews is disabled
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its happening, because you're using auto-layout. You'll have to check in the auto-layout parameters.